# Merging two UIImages faster than CGContextDrawImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm merging two UIImages into one context. It works, but it performs pretty slow and I'm in the need of a faster solution. As my solution is it takes about 400ms to make the `mergeImage: withImage:` call on an iPad 1G.

Here's what I do:

```
-(CGContextRef)mergeImage:(UIImage*)img1 withImage:(UIImage*)img2
{
    CGSize size = [ImageToolbox getScreenSize];
    CGContextRef context = [ImageToolbox createARGBBitmapContextFromImageSize:CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height)];

    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentSaturation);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), img1.CGImage);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), img2.CGImage);


    return context;
}
```

And here's the static methods from the ImageToolbox class:

```
static CGRect screenRect;

+ (CGContextRef)createARGBBitmapContextFromImageSize:(CGSize)imageSize
{
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    size_t pixelsWide = imageSize.width;
    size_t pixelsHigh = imageSize.height;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}

+(CGSize)getScreenSize
{
    if (screenRect.size.width == 0 && screenRect.size.height == 0)
    {
        screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];    

    }
    return CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width-20);
}
```

Any suggestions to increase the performance?

Comment: Can you measure how long each method is taking?

Comment: The drawImage calls takes about 400 ms, the rest of the methods are under 10ms each.

Comment: Are these images that you can combine beforehand and ship with your app?  The performance hit is most likely due to some combo of your colorspace and premultiplying of alpha.  Play around with those a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did no manage to find a faster way of merging the images. I reduced the images sizes to make the operation faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using Instruments to profile what message is taking the most time so you can really break it down.  Also, I have written a couple methods which I think should do the same thing with a lot less code, but you must have everything written out the way you do to really keep things customizable.  Here they are anyways:

```
-(CGContextRef)mergeImage:(UIImage *)img1 withImage:(UIImage *)img2
{  
  CGSize size = [ImageToolbox getScreenSize];
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 1.0);

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentSaturation);

  [img1 drawInRect:rect];
  [img2 drawInRect:rect];

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return context;
}
```

Or if you wanted the combined image right away:

```
- (UIImage *)mergeImage:(UIImage *)img1 withImage:(UIImage *)img2
{
  CGSize size = [ImageToolbox getScreenSize];
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 1.0);

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentSaturation);

  [img1 drawInRect:rect];
  [img2 drawInRect:rect];

  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return image;
}
```

I have no idea if they would be faster or not, but I really wouldn't know how to speed up what you have very easily unless you had the instruments profile break down.

In any case, I hope this helps.

Comment: I just realized there may be all sorts of dumb memory issues with my methods but they are simple fixes.  You could easily retain the context if you need to or what not.  But you get the idea.

Comment: Your solutions does not work without a CGContextDrawImage call. You'll have to make a CGContextDrawImage after the drawInRect calls. But I was able to get the execution times of the methods: drawInRect takes 400ms by itself which ends in 200ms on img_decode_stage and 200ms on img_interpolate_read.

Comment: Ahh yes you could easily use that instead of drawInRect.  Just goes to show that less isn't always better with code.  Obviously in any solution the messages which will take the longest time is the actual drawing messages.  For yours you'll have to get nit picky if you really want to squeeze out performance.  For example: instead of using CGRectMake twice use it once in a var and reuse it, since men allocation is slightly taxing though with a little struct like that it probably won't matter.  When you assign the context use the var size instead of Allocating a new CGSize.

Comment: Also try putting your get Screen size message inline (as in instead of putting the code in a separate method put the code in the mergeImage method) and see how much extra performance that squeezes out.  Reuse CGSize and CGRects as much as possible in vars without using CGSizeMake or CGRectMake.